# Multiple lags of time-series in one matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, time-series

Let's say I have some time-series `z`.

To get the first lag, I can do:

```
x1 = z(1:end-1);
y  = z(2:end);
```

Then both x1 and y will have the same dimensions. How do I do this in a more general way to get also the lags of say 5 periods and 1 periods together in one matrix with same dimensions?

If I do

```
x1 = z(1:end-1);
x5 = z(1:end-5);
y  = z(2:end);
```

then x1 will have a different length than x5.

Comment: You can for example use powers of circulant matrices multiplied together with cropped unity matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circulant matrix $$C_4 = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]$$
produces a lag of 1 for a 4 sample long signal. ${C_4}^2$ produces a lag of 2 and so on. Then you may want to crop the data that will "overlap" in the circulation. You can do that with a crop matrix: $\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0
\end{array}\right]$ or in general $[\bf I_n, 0]$ where the zero pads number of columns required to make the matrix multiplication ${{\bf MC}_n}^k$ well defined.